# Schema markup votes

Tags: joomla-3.x, json, microdata

Good evening.
I need help with schema markup for product.
Microdata or ld+json.
I managed to markup content but i can't make aggregateRating to get rating from standard vote plugin.
I tried several plugins, but every plugin has its issues.
So i prefere to insert microdata or ld+json manually to my articles.
What is the syntax to put article rating in my markup under Product, name, description etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it with [yrvote plugin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/yrvote/). With `{yrvote}` insertion where you want to show star rating, you can manage microdata format and aggregateRating.